# Hilios Jquery Countdown localization

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm using Hilios Jquery Countdown https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown

Example of multiple instances:

```
<div data-countdown="2014/06/20 20:00"></div>
<div data-countdown="2014/06/21 20:00"></div>
<div data-countdown="2014/06/22 20:00"></div>
```

Js:

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
    $this.countdown(finalDate, function (event) {
        var format = '%H:%M:%S';
        if (event.offset.days > 0) {
            format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
        }
        if (event.offset.weeks > 0) {
            format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
        }
        $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
    });
});
```

The problem here is, that if I select some European language(German, Slovenian) in the browser, the browser automatically formats string date from 2014/06/20 to 2014.06.20 which makes the script not working. Why is this happening? Am I passing the date value to data attribute wrong?

When I see their examples here: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/multiple-instances.html it works properly with all languages... but they dont have an example of HTML implementation, only the way I am doing it, but somehow for them it works.

Anyone had issues with this?

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.